# Maven: create separate jar file while packing is pom

Tags: java, maven, jar

I am trying to have Maven to create a separate `jar` with `resources` folder only. The project structure is as follows (there is no `main` folder so no `main` class):

```
db
src
|--resources
   |--flyway
```

while the `pom.xml` looks like this (**Please mind that I am aware that the `packaging` is set to `pom` as it has to stay that way**):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.myproject</groupId>
    <artifactId>myproject</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>My Project</name>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test-jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <classesDirectory>src</classesDirectory>
                    <includes>
                        <include>
                            none of the paths worked
                        </include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jfrog.buildinfo</groupId>
                <artifactId>artifactory-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <inherited>false</inherited>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>build-info</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>publish</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <publisher>
                                <contextUrl>http://mvn.mycompany/artifactory</contextUrl>
                                <username>${username}</username>
                                <password>${password}</password>
                                <repoKey>libs-release-local</repoKey>
                                <snapshotRepoKey>libs-snapshot-local</snapshotRepoKey>
                            </publisher>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <id>central</id>
            <name>bintray</name>
            <url>https://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <id>central</id>
            <name>bintray-plugins</name>
            <url>https://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

I tried using `maven-jar-plugin` but unfortunately I could not make it work so that it would produce for me a `.jar` file containing `resources/flyway` folder. The `pom.xml` packaging has to stay `pom` so there is no way I could switch it back to `jar` (it would obviously solve my problems). How could I produce a jar package is such scenario so that it would end up in the `.m2` folder?

The reason for all of that is I would like to have separate `jar` package for my flyway scripts and I could stick that dependency wherever I would like.

Comment: First I strongly recommend to follow conventions and put your resources into `src/main/resources` . There you could put simply the directory `resources/flyway` which would end up in your jar file. But change your packaging type to `jar` that makes it easier. I don't understand why are you so violent to say `The pom.xml packaging has to stay pom so there is no way I could switch it back to jar`... in particular: `it would obviously solve my problems`? So you have changed the structure/packaging and you have problems? Not astonishing. So change it... that's the solution.

Answer (score 1):

The default location for Maven resources is `src/main/resources`, and for test resources is `src/test/resources`. Best practice is to follow Maven conventions if possible.

If you can't use the standard directory structure for some reason, then you'll need to add a [`<resources>` element](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/resource-directory.html):

```
<project>
...
   <build>
   ...
   <resources>
      <resource>
         <directory>src/resources</directory>
      </resource>
   </resources>

   <plugins>
       <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>resources</id>
                    <phase>process-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
       </plugin>

       <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <!-- jar, war, ear, assembly.... -->
            <artifactId>packaging-plugin-here</artifactId>
       </plugin>

   </plugins>
   </build>
...
</project>
```

Comment: @BartRobeyns, artifacts can be produced with pom packaging. I've done it, many times. It needs explicit plugin config which I forgot to add in my first post. OP also needs to ensure  any plugins/goals added are explicitly bound to the desired phase as only `install:install` and `deploy:deploy` are part of the built-in lifecycle. And that said - following Maven convention and using `jar` packaging is still a better choice most of the time, as @khmarbaise says.

Comment: You are right; the small change in resources would indeed make the OP's pom work. I'll delete my comment :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the posibility to create a separate module?
If so you could keep the pom packaging and do something like this:

```
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<modules>
    <module>resources</module>
</modules>
```

And in the "resources" module you can have a pom.xml with jar packaging.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comments that say it would be better to put this in a separate module. Still, that shouldn't prevent you from learning how it can be done.
The [maven assembly plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) makes this easy:

A project with flyway scripts in src/main/resources/flyway, having this pom.xml

```
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptors>
                        <descriptor>src/assembly/flyway.xml</descriptor>
                    </descriptors>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

referencing the 'assembly-configuration' in src/main/assembly/flyway.xml:

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.1.0"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-2.1.0.xsd">
  <id>flyway</id>
  <formats>
    <format>zip</format>
  </formats>
  <fileSets>
    <fileSet>
        <directory>src/main/resources/flyway</directory>
    </fileSet>
  </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

will produce a zip-file at package time containing your flyway scripts.
(if you really want to stick to src/resources/flyway you can easily adapt it)

Note that while this sample use pom as packaging, it would also work with a packaging=jar; it would simply create a second artifact next to the primary one.